# sub appends Nil to the end in Raku

Tags: raku

```
my sub e($r) { printf("%d, ", $_) for 1..$r}
say e(5);
```

returns `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Nil` that is, the `sub` and/or `say` consistently adds a *Nil* to the end.

I first tried it using rakudo version 2020.02. I've tried now using the latest version 2020.12.1 and that *Nil* is still there. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Nil` is the return value of the sub `e`.

You either want

```
my sub e($r) { printf("%d, ", $_) for 1..$r}
e(5);
```

or

```
my sub e($r) { map { sprintf("%d, ", $_) }, 1..$r }
.say for e(5);
```